# Where and how to put the package.json in a tgz dependency

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to build a node library that will be stored into a .tgz

The issue is when I install this lib in another npm project, I have an error:

> Non-registry package missing package.json:
> easy-rules-core@file:/Users/sbuisson/.m2/repository/org/jeasy/easy-rules-core-js/3.2.4/easy-rules-core-js-3.2.4.tgz.

The file structure of my tgz:

```
easy-rules-core-js-3.2.4.tgz
  -> package
     ->package.json
     ->index.js
     ->node_modules
```

I've also tried without success:

```
easy-rules-core-js-3.2.4.tgz
     ->package.json
     ->index.js
     ->node_modules
```

Where should I put the package.json?

Bonus question: Do I need to put the node_modules folder into the tgz?

Comment: The error message seems to be coming from a Maven path, can you confirm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the `npm pack` command in your project folder. It should create a .tgz file structured correctly. It should be something like this (without the `node_modules` folder):

```
easy-rules-core-js-3.2.4.tgz
  -> package
     ->package.json
     ->index.js
```

Then copy the .tgz file in your parent module's root folder and run:
`npm install ./easy-rules-core-js-3.2.4.tgz`.

This will handle the installation while adding the following line to your package.json:
`"easy-rules-core-js": "file:easy-rules-core-js-3.2.4.tgz"`. Alternatively you can add the dependency manually to the package.json.

More information:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack
- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Is it possible to put the `.tgz` file in another place rather than parent module's root folder?